# sql 42S22 error in Laravel (choosing a column I didn't mention)

Tags: laravel

I am doing a basic project in Laravel, when trying to delete an entry, it generates this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `employees` where `id` = 6 limit 1)

and it is true I don't have a column named 'id', instead I have employee_id, but why is it choosing id instead of employee_id?

Please explain from where did it bring this id column?

Comment: Laravel assumes 'id' is the primary key unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: It it's an "emplees" table why would the column be named "employee_id" when "id" would be suitable enough? It's implied that the "id" column is specific to the employee's table, no?

Comment: You can override the primary key in your model if you want/need to. But if you don't need to, then rename the column to 'id' because it's implied.

Comment: In your **Employee** model (`Employee.php`), add `protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';`.

Comment: thanks, a lot i got it

Comment: @M.Gamie Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem. This will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Employee model** (`Employee.php`), add

`protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';`

This will tell Laravel to use `employee_id` as the primary key for `Empolyee` objects.